# Why DecisionTreeClassifier gives 100% result?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have done the following:

1. Split test and train data.
2. Ensure nothing is common between test and train data.
3. Do up scaling to make train data have equal number of "Yes" and "No".

**However, I always get a 1.0 best parameter. Why is this?**

This is the entire code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from random import randrange
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as tm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
```

Reference (for converting text > numeric):

https://www.kaggle.com/pavansubhasht/ibm-hr-analytics-attrition-dataset/discussion/86957

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furkan-ozbudak/machine-learning/master/input.csv"

# Import data
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(url)

# Drop non-priority features/columns
dataFrame = dataFrame.drop(columns=['Education', 'EmployeeCount', 'NumCompaniesWorked', 'Over18'])
features = [
            'Attrition',
            'BusinessTravel',
            'Department',
            'EducationField',
            'Gender',
            'JobRole',
            'MaritalStatus',
            'OverTime'
]
stringToNumericDict = {
    "Yes":1, "No":0, "Y":1, "N":0,
    "Non-Travel":0, "Travel_Frequently":2, "Travel_Rarely": 3,
    "Research & Development": 2, "Human Resources":"1", "Sales": 3,
    "Life Sciences": 2, "Medical":4, "Other":5, "Marketing": 3, "Technical Degree":6,
    "Male": 2, "Female":1,
    "Laboratory Technician": 3, "Healthcare Representative": 1, "Manufacturing Director":5,
      "Sales Executive": 8, "Research Scientist": 7, "Research Director": 6,"Sales Representative": 9,
      "Manager": 4,
    "Married": 2, "Divorced": 1, "Single": 3,
    }

# Convert Alphabets > Numeric
for feature in features:
  dataFrame[feature].replace(stringToNumericDict, inplace=True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 
y = dataFrame['Attrition']
```

Here, I am splitting my data to test and train.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataFrame, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

Here, I am upsampling train data because it has majority No. After this step Yes and No are both 50% each.

```
from sklearn.utils import resample

df_majority = X_train[X_train['Attrition']==0] # 0 = No
df_minority = X_train[X_train['Attrition']==1]
 
print("Count of 'No': %d(majority), Count of Yes: %d(minority)" % (len(df_majority), len(df_minority)))

# Upsample minority class
df_minority_upsampled = resample(df_minority, 
                                 replace=True,     # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=869,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=50)  # reproducible results
 
# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
X_train = pd.concat([df_majority, df_minority_upsampled])
 
# Display new class counts
X_train['Attrition'].value_counts()

# Change y_train in because X_train changed
y_train = X_train['Attrition'].values

sns.countplot(X_train['Attrition'])

all_cols = list(X_train.columns)
X_train.merge(X_test.drop_duplicates(subset=all_cols), how='inner')

# Train once
```

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

Train the model in train data and test the data in test data:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict the class of samples
y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
#clf.score(X_test, y_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict)
accuracy_score(y_test,y_predict)*100 
classification_report(y_test, y_predict)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)

from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
precision_score(y_test, y_predict)

from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
f1_score(y_test, y_predict)
```

Comment: This question does belong to ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @navule I appreciate your analysis. The question is answered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got everything right, your target variable is the *Attrition* attribute in your original dataframe. However, I did not see that you are removing this attribute from your sets of features, namely `X_train` and `X_test`.

It is no wonder if you get 1.0 for all scores if you pass the target you are trying to predict as a feature to the classifier.

I think the easiest thing you can do to resolve this in your code snippet is to call `.pop()` on `X_train` and `X_test` just before you fit your classifier:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

X_train.pop('Attrition') # <-- remove target variable
X_test.pop('Attrition') # <-- remove target variable

clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
```

This should resolve the issue as you are not passing the desired outcome as input anymore.

Comment: Thanks you saved me in a project demo.